# Where is the documentation for the "exists" routing constraint in ASP.NET MVC5+?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

In learning about the area handling story in MVC6, I [keep](http://www.codecompiled.com/creating-a-new-project-in-asp-net-5/) [coming](http://shellmonger.com/2015/04/08/configuring-areas-in-asp-net-vnext/) [across](http://timjames.me/blog/2014/12/13/mvc-areas-with-vnext/) [blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254771/using-areas-in-asp-net-5) [posts](http://forums.asp.net/t/2002464.aspx?Working+with+areas+in+ASP+NET+MVC+6+and+vnext) that have `area:exists` in a route pattern, but no matter how hard I search, I can't find anything about this at all in any Microsoft documentation, and none of the blog posts I've found explain what it's doing or mention where that bit of information came from.

Where is this constrained explained, and where is the comprehensive, up-to-date, canonical documentation for built-in route patterns and constraints? For the record, I am aware of [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#url_patterns) page, but it's structured more like a tutorial than a canonical reference.

*If anyone from Microsoft is reading this, http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/api-reference leads to a page with next to no information and an unsynced table of contents that I can't find what I want within. And your `RouteAttribute` class reference has no links to anything explaining what a url pattern should look like.*

**EDIT**

So after some deeper digging, I found this:
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/48bfdceea6d243c5ec8d6e00f450f8fe7cce59f7/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/MvcCoreRouteOptionsSetup.cs#L26

So it's related to `KnownRouteValueConstraint`, which led me to this:
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/e0b8532735997c439e11fff68dd342d5af59f05f/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/KnownRouteValueConstraint.cs#L26-L40

So I guess that means the constraint simply makes sure the captured value is non-null. I still don't know where the canonical source for that information is though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ASP.NET 5/MVC 6 is [not yet officially released](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap) and at the moment the API is not yet stable, it isn't that surprising that the documentation has not been completed yet.

Do note that ASP.NET vNext is open source, so where documentation is lacking you can always look at tests to try to work out what to do. [Here are some](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/e0b8532735997c439e11fff68dd342d5af59f05f/test/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FunctionalTests/InlineConstraintTests.cs#L24) that test the inline constraint `area:exists`.

```
[Fact]
public async Task RoutingToANonExistantArea_WithExistConstraint_RoutesToCorrectAction()
{
    // Arrange
    var server = TestHelper.CreateServer(_app, SiteName, _configureServices);
    var client = server.CreateClient();

    // Act
    var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost/area-exists/Users");

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
    var returnValue = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Assert.Equal("Users.Index", returnValue);
}

[Fact]
public async Task RoutingToANonExistantArea_WithoutExistConstraint_RoutesToIncorrectAction()
{
    // Arrange
    var server = TestHelper.CreateServer(_app, SiteName, _configureServices);
    var client = server.CreateClient();

    // Act
    var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost/area-withoutexists/Users");

    // Assert
    var exception = response.GetServerException();
    Assert.Equal("The view 'Index' was not found." +
                 " The following locations were searched:__/Areas/Users/Views/Home/Index.cshtml__" +
                 "/Areas/Users/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml__/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml.",
                 exception.ExceptionMessage);
}
```

Comment: You are right of course, and obviously an unreleased beta is not going to be completely documented. In this case though, I had the funny idea that `{area:exists}` came from MVC5. In retrospect, this was clearly a false assumption and I'm not sure why I thought it... You'll note in my question that I edited it to mention that I'd read the source code and figured it out. Thanks for the answer in any case.